# Pass variable with django form submission

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I have a search box at the top of my sidemenu.  This search bar searches across all views (tasks, lists, and information).  The results are shown across these three categories, but lists and information are collapsed by default to make the view easier to read.

Instead, I would like to determine which side menu the user used to search, and collapse the other two categories when returning the results.

So if the user was looking at tasks, the search results would list the tasks, but return lists and information results collapsed.  If the user used the search box in lists, the results would list the list items, but collapse tasks and information.

The same function is used to handle all of the search results:

```
def search(request):

    query_string = ''
    search_results = SortedDict([])

    if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
        query_string = request.GET['q']

        entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['name', 'notes',])
```

getquery()  searches the database for the query_string

This function is called from the template:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url search %}" style="display:inline;" >
    <input name="q" class="span9" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" id="appendedInputButton" size="16" type="text">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">
        <i class="icon-search" title="Search"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

**How might I pass either the current url or some other template variable along with this form submission so that I have some template info available in the search function?**  This would then allow me to pass information to the search results that would tell the template which categories to collapse.

Comment: Would it be feasible to add a hidden input in your search form that identifies the view it was called from?  (e.g. <input type="hidden" name="view" value="{{ view_name_set_in_view }}" />)

Comment: Try get parameters. action="{% url search %}?param1={{val1}}&param2={{val2}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most foolproof way is to use separate buttons. If you give each a name and only the appropriate one is shown when a particular view is active, you can tell which view was active from the existence of the button's name in the POST.

The only other route would be to create a hidden field, and set the value of the field appropriately, with JavaScript, when the view changes.